# How to return the value of the braced portion of a Registry Key

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I am trying to build an install that will set various GPO's for me. The Registry Key contains a GUID. There are several listed in the Registry. My question is three fold:

1. What does this GUID represent? Is this a unique identifier for the machine?
2. How do I determine which one to use?
3. Is there a function or procedure I can run to capture this value?

I tried this but could not get it to return anything.

```
[Code]
procedure StoreHwID();
    var
    HwId: String;

begin
   RegQueryStringValue(HKCU,'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects','Machine', HwId);
   MsgBox('Value is "' + HwId + '"', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

Root: HKCU; Subkey:"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{{8040B178-46A6-4531-85A5-797EE99EA211}Machine\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"; ValueType: dword; ValueName:"BranchReadinessLevel"; ValueData: 32; Permissions: users-modify; Components: APC Classic Workstation;
```

Comment: You have 2 questions: 1) About GPO: That's not [tag:inno-setup] question, so you will hardly get an answer fort that here. And it's not even a programming question, so it should go to [su]. 2) About reading the registry key in Inno Setup: But to ask that question, you need to tell us what exactly do you want to read, what you possibly do not even know at this moment. - Though from some references on Internet, I see that the actual key might be like `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{EXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}Machine`, what does not match your code.

Comment: OK, I maybe understand now a bit - You want to find the value of `{EXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}` - right? I do not have those keys, so I do not know if there's only one or is there a more (probably more, considering your second question).

Comment: Yes, I need to get the value of {EXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} programmatically to apply to the [Registry] section code in INNO. They are unique from computer to computer and there are often more than one.

Comment: OK, do you know which one you need?

Comment: That is part of the issue. I do not know which one.

Comment: OK, then your question is a way too broad. See my first comment. – First find out what key do you need to use (or ask at [su]). And then come here to ask how to implement that in Inno Setup.